# How RTSP handle taking two stream from camera which gives stream on same port?

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp

If camera giving stream on one port , then how rtsp taking two stream parallel from camera?

Comment: Have you got any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: No , but I have found that RTSP itself create multiple port for taking data in thread and give output to one port.That's why some IP camera give error or warring message that "Camera support this much stream only".

Comment: Ok I got it, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Welcome.....lucifer.